# Lightning component in custom container component on community a page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, partner-communities

I have create a simple lightning button component which can be placed on a community page. I would like to add multiple "buttons" in one container with a certain styling applied to it.

Is it possible to create a lightning component which can contain other lightning components? Like how custom tabs work on a community page, you can drag components on a tab. If it is possible, how?

Regards,
Stijn

Answer (score 0):

Right now, it's not possible. There's an idea for that though and you can vote for it. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dx5HAAS